# Lens Studio - How can I get the name or properties of the image I clicked?

Tags: javascript, image, mouseevent

There are multiple clickable images on the screen. I want to keep which image I clicked in a variable. How can I do this with javascript? Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener on the images click event, then take the src for example of the image clicked and store it in a variable like this:

```
$('img').click(function (e) {
    var clickedImge = '';
    clickedImge = e.target.src;
});
```

Comment: when i write like this i get an error like this : 15:37:40 ReferenceError: identifier '$' undefined
    at onTouchStartEvent (Scripts/MainScript.js:12) preventsyield

Comment: I think you are using an old jquery version, change the $ by jQuery and test, If you still have an issue please tell me what jquery version are you using.

Comment: Working in a lens studio might be a little different? I don't know as this is my first time using it. I downloaded the latest version of jQuery but nothing changed.

Comment: So you should first fix the jQuery issues that you have then you can use its functionalities. Sorry I've never worked before in a lens studio.